# How to make path param to be optional in react router dom(v4)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

This is my code which I don't think is right and redundant:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}/>
 <Route path="/:filter" component={App}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I think exact={true} is redundant since I can simply do path="/(:filter)" in previous react router versions? I don't wanna use history.push :(

This is how I usd my NavLink in my Footer Component:

```
const Footer = () => (
  <p>
    Show:
    {" "}
    <FilterLink filter="all"> 
      All 
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="active">
      Active
    </FilterLink>
    {", "}
    <FilterLink filter="completed">
      Completed
    </FilterLink>
  </p>
);
```

and my FilterLink:

```
const FilterLink = ({ filter, children }) => (
  <NavLink 
    to={ filter === 'all' ? '' : filter }
    activeStyle={{
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'red'
    }}
  >
  {children}
  </NavLink>
);
```

The path is changing, example: localhost:3000/active but the style has no effect, but it affects the all? when I am on localhost:3000/?

Answer (score 2):

In react-router v4 you can defined an optional path parameter like

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Route path="/:filter?" component={App}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Path parameter must be defined in a manner which is as per the npm package **[path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)** understands as mentioned in the [**react-router docs**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string)

Comment: when I am applying activeStyle, it is not working on my localhost:3000 and not on other filters?

Comment: what do you mean by when you are applying activeStyle

Comment: If you don't add active style then

Comment: all have the same style, just adds underline below, but I want to add activeStyle which I cannot accomplish

Comment: maybe <NavLink 
    to={ filter === 'all' ? '/' : '/' + filter }
    activeStyle={{
      textDecoration: 'none',
      color: 'red'
    }}
  >

Comment: All is always active...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146290/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-i-am-newbie).