# How to handle empty URL parameter in react router dom (4.xx)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have route defined as below :

```
<Route path='/result/:searchTerm' component={Result}/>
```

It works fine. For example `localhost:3000/result/cat` page works. But when the user decided to remove the `:searchTerm` from the URL and opens just `localhost:3000/result/` it shows empty page. No errors or anything. Just empty page. It is not even hitting my component `{Result}` too.

So my doubt is how to handle this scenario.? Say I want to redirect the user who tries to open `/result/` without `:searchTerms` to my index page.? How to do that.?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe you can just add a question mark for an optional parameter, so:

```
<Route path='/result/:searchTerm?' component={Result} />
```

This works because React Router 4 uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#optional) to interpret its path property.

To answer the last part of your question, you could simply test the value of `:searchTerm` and if it was undefined, redirect the user.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect the user to another page if the param is not added, you would do the following

```
<Switch>
   <Redirect from='/result/' to='/' exact />
   <Route path='/result/:searchTerm' component={Result}/>
</Switch>
```

However if you wish to show the same page then without the params too, you could just use optional path params.
 Check this answer for more details: [How to make path param to be optional in react router dom(v4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462158/how-to-make-path-param-to-be-optional-in-react-router-domv4/44462748#44462748)

Comment: Tried this. Not working. I mean '/result/cat' also gets redirected to '/'

Comment: Updated the answer, should be exact instead of strict

Comment: BTW if you're curious, quite a few people think `exact` should be the default, but [it's contentious](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/5612).

Answer (score 1):

`Switch` is a component used to render routes exclusively. So, in general, at the end of children inside `Switch`, you can provide a default route (in your case the index page) for any path that you don't explicitly specify in other routes.

Eg:

```
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'
            component={()=>(<Redirect to='/index'/>)}/>
          <Route exact path='/index' component={Index}/>
          <Route path='/result/:searchTerm' component={Result}/>
          .
          .
          // default route, gets rendered if none of the above match:
          <Route component={NotFound404}/>
        </Switch>
```